# how to push json data into array with 2 level or n level

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

It may be a silly question, but right now I can't figure it out. so I'm in need.

I'm showing static data but i'd like to make it dynamic in future.

```
 var name = [];
 name.push({ name: "Gareth" });
 name[0].push({ name: "john" }); // This statement doesn't work as name[0]!=[] I guess.
 name[0].push({name:"dolly"});
```

I want to get an out put like,

```
 +name  <--- expandable

     +0   <--- expandable

          name : "gareth"

          +0  <--- expandable
             name: "john"

          +1   <--- expandable
             name: "dolly"
```

I know its not a difficult one. But i'm unable to figure it out right now. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're correct, you would have to change your data structure, perhaps, you could add an ``arr`` property to your ``name[0]``. and do ``name[0].arr[0] --> {name:"john"}``

Comment: how to do it? can you show me through code? considering its gonna have dynamic appoarch if possible. else do it for at least Oth index.

Comment: this sounds like an `X-Y` problem. Start by explaining use case

Answer (score 1):

You can't `push` anything onto `name[0]` as it is not an array but you can still assign elements with number's to it and create your own push.

```
var makePushable = function (obj) {
  obj.push = function (item) {
    this[this.length] = item;
    this.length++;
  };
  obj.length = 0; //Keep track of how many elements
}

var name = [];
name.push({ name: "Gareth" });

makePushable(name[0]);
name[0].push({ name: "john" });
name[0].push({ name:"dolly" });
```

And we get:

```
name[0]    ---> {
    name:"gareth",

    0: {name:"john"},
    1: {name:"dolly"},

    length: 2,
    push: function () { ... }
}
name[0][0] ---> {name:"john"}
name[0][1] ---> {name:"dolly"}
```

If you don't want `push` and `length` to show up on `for ( prop in xxx ) if (xxx.hasOwnProperty(prop))`, you could make a class like so:

```
var Pushable = function (obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    this[i] = obj[i];
  }
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, {
    push: function (item) {
      this[this.length] = item;
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this).length++;
    },
    length: 0
  });
};

Pushable.prototype.push = function (item) {
  this[this.length] = item;
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).length++;
};
Pushable.prototype.length = 0;

var name = [];
name.push(new Pushable({ name:"Gareth" }));
name[0].push(new Pushable({ name: "john" }));
name[0].push(new Pushable({ name:"dolly" }));
name[0][1].push(new Pushable({ name:"last kid" }));
```

You could make the `push` function, automatically create a `Pushable` class for you if you wanted.

Comment: but `for ( prop in xxx )` will give you `name`, `length`, `0`, `1` & `push`

Comment: @NULL Yes it will, you could make a new class instead.

Comment: @micronyks What do you mean? What do you expect and what happens instead? NVM, I forgot to increment ``length``.

Comment: Output should be: +name=> expand it. it gives you +[0]=> expand it it gives you name : "gareth" +0, +1.... I hope you understand it. it belongs to .net framework output which could be seen through output intellisense....

Comment: I have mentioned which kinda output i want to have...see the output again in my above question....

Comment: @micronyks I think this should work for all intents and purposes I think you have. But this is dodgy and you should probably change the criteria in which you need to structure this.

Comment: @micronyks Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62917/discussion-between-winestone-and-micronyks).

Answer (score 0):

FIRST CHANGE YOU ARRAY NAME 
try this

```
 var m = {}; m.name=[];
 m.name.push({ name: "Gareth" });
 m.name.push({ name: "john" }); // This statement doesn't work as name[0]!=[] I guess.
 m.name.push({name:"dolly"});
```

out put

[image]

Comment: You in array set object and in object not [0] item

Comment: Have you checked an out put of it? it doesn't give me an output that i'm lookin' for... It works but not the way i want. If you could help me more.

Comment: Output should be: +name=> expand it. it gives you +[0]=> expand it it gives you name : "gareth" +0, +1....
I hope you understand it. it belongs to .net framework output which  could be seen through output intellisense....

Comment: Oh no... Should not be like this...It should be lik Oth index must contain {name:gareth, oth obj,1st obj}...

Comment: I have mentioned which kinda output i want to have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62916/discussion-between-harutyun-abgaryan-and-micronyks).

Comment: Nope.In your output if you expand Oth index it surely gets you Gareth name. but not other two objects which must have been pushed to the same index... In your output they both objects are separated from Oth index... Connect them with Oth index. So if you now expand Oth index you get {"gareth", object, object}. I hope you get this.